# Does negative vs positive matching impact firewall performance?

Tags: performance, firewall

I am curious if using negative vs. positive matching impacts the performance of the `netfilter` stack. e.g. is `iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -s 192.168.0.0/16 -j DROP` equivalent to `iptables -I INPUT -p tcp !-s 192.168.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT` in terms of performance?

I have been told that negative matching might yield far worse performance, but I do not think it is supported by any facts; for all I know, it is the number of matching iterations (i.e. rules) which affects performance most. Unfortunately I do not have a test setup at hand with which I could test that hypothesis.

The reason I am asking this is the company I work for uses many small (both in size and in computing capabilities) MikroTik routers and I am trying to come up with a reasonable best practices firewall policy. Apparently RouterOS, the proprietary OS MikroTik ships with those routers, is based on Linux kernel 2.6.16, so I believe that limitations of a vanilla 2.6.16 kernel apply there too. As the person who claims there is a difference in performance is my boss, I want to be sure that I may safely ignore the claim.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My first instinct is that in your example the cost and complexity of your rules is identical and which is better is as much personal preference as anything else. The inversion generally is *not* more complex as a matching rule in netfilter.

The general consensus seems to be that the number and ordering of rules is much more important for optimal performance then how you craft individual rules, although you can make gains there too.

The Linux netfilter firewall normally operates under a first match basis and the rules in each chain are processed sequentially, so the fewer rules needed to be processed before hitting a match, the higher your performance will be.

That is the reason most firewall configurations have something like: `-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT` as the first rule. Typically that single rule matches the majority of all traffic on reasonably busy sites. (As in upwards of 99% of all traffic...)

Now the remaining firewall rules are only to be triggered and processed for new connections, significantly reducing the amount of processing required.

Since the rules are processed in order, from an performance perspective it makes sense to order the rules by how likely they are triggered.

e.g. on a webserver the vast majority of traffic will be on the default HTTP ports. Therefore a rule like `-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j ACCEPT` effecting the majority of your users should be your second rule and not as rule number 199 after a whole range of rules that are unlikely to match for anyone but a small number of specific users and/or uncommon protocols.

As far as crafting rules, by using the correct modules like for instance multiport and iprange you can create smart rules rather then numerous individual rules.

Comment: Thank you, it's pretty much what I thought. Thanks for the rule ordering tips too, the answer will be much more useful to other people this way. +1 and accept from me.